# Is it possible to have one crate with both procedural macros and logic?

Tags: macros, rust, rust-macros

When you want to share a library that uses a procedural macro, is the dual crate approach `foo`/`foo_derive` inevitable?

I would like to provide a crate that has the logic **and** the macros. The first thing I tried was:

```
my_proc_macro
├── Cargo.toml
├── src/lib.rs
└── my_crate
    ├── Cargo.toml
    └── src/lib.rs
```

In the `my_proc_macro` crate, I tried to `pub use my_crate::*;` but it is forbidden to do so: the compiler refused to build this.

Is it possible to do this the other way around? I mean: import the procedural macro crate into the library and then reexport the macro?

Comment: I'm quite sure it can be done the other way around, but I'm not sure how. Look for example at [`rental`](https://crates.io/crates/rental), it has `rental-impl` as a dependency, but the user code does not have to write `extern crate rental_impl` so the `rental!` macro must be reexported by the main crate.

Comment: @rodrigo Unfortunately, I do not think that's what `rental` does: it exports [a "regular" macro](https://github.com/jpernst/rental/blob/master/src/lib.rs#L220) that does the derive

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's actually quite straight-forward to re-export macros.  Simply use

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate my_proc_macro;
```

in the root of `my_crate`.

[The `serde` crate can be used this way when enabling the feature `serde_derive`.](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/blob/master/serde/src/lib.rs#L299-L305)

In the 2018 edition, you can also [explicitly re-export proc macros using `use` declarations](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/edition-guide/rust-2018/macros/macro-changes.html#procedural-macros).